# custom helper for checkbox not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

When using html helper CheckBoxFor() one would do this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.active)
```

and that will result in html code like this:

```
    <input class="check-box" id="active" name="active" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="active" type="hidden"  value="false" />
```

my problem is, the html/css template I am using needs an specific tag right after the checkbox field to work. (it is needed for some css/jquery effects on the checkbox). so I would need to modify CheckBoxFor() to generate this instead:

```
<input class="check-box" id="active" name="active" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<i class="no-rounded"></i>
<input name="active" type="hidden"  value="false" />
```

I have tried creating a custom extension method like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomCheckboxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression)
{
    var data = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    string propertyName = data.PropertyName;
    string s = "";
    s += "<input class=\"check-box\" id=\"" + propertyName + "\" name=\"" + propertyName+ "\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" />";
    s += "<i class=\"no-rounded\"></i>";
    s += "<input name=\"" + propertyName + "\" type=\"hidden\"  value=\"false\" />";
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(s.ToString());
```

and calling it with

```
@Html.CustomCheckboxFor(model => model.active)
```

This is painting the checkbox ok, and css/jquery effects are working, 
**but** on create or edit view for example, it is not binding to the property on the model (if the property is true, it should load the form with the checkbox checked, and it doesnt)

How can I do this?

**UPDATE:**
ok, I made some advance, its working now, but I bet there must be a better, more elegant way of doing this... what I have done is to let the .net helper do the job of generating html code for checkbox and hidden fields. then i got that string and just insert the needed tag in between both fields, and return that:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString UnifyCheckboxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression)
            {
                string s = helper.CheckBoxFor(expression).ToString();
                string part1 = s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf(">")+1);
                string part2 = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(">")+1);
                string str = part1 + "<i class=\"no-rounded\"></i>" + part2;
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(str.ToString());
   }
```

**UPDATE2**: With info given by @Joshua Duxbury in the comments: if creating custom helper, the framework wont try to bind it, so we must do the binding ourselves on the helper. So the initial code works by just adding that logic:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomCheckboxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression)
    {
        var data = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
        string propertyName = data.PropertyName;
        string s = "";
        s += "<input class=\"check-box\" id=\"" + propertyName + "\" name=\"" + propertyName+ "\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" " + ((data.Model.Equals(true)) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") +"/>";
        s += "<i class=\"no-rounded\"></i>";
        s += "<input name=\"" + propertyName + "\" type=\"hidden\"  value=\"false\" />";
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(s.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Your hard coding `value="true"` on the input tags, shouldn't this be set based on the model property?

Comment: If I understood how checkboxes work in .net mvc (I could be wrong), the value of the checkbox should be always true, and the value of the hidden should be always false... (this is because html checkboxes are only sent back to server when submitting form IF they are checked). this way, when the checkbox is not checked, the hidden field will still be send back to server, with value false...

Comment: yeah, I though just by making the name of the checkbox the same as the name of the property, .net would bind them... but that doesnt seem to be the case lol.

Comment: No, it won't bind the value of the checkbox based on the name if you've made a custom HTML helper. You need to set the value.

Comment: @Joshua Duxbury ok that seems like the correct answer... now I am checking if the property is true in the model and if so, write the "checked=checked" part when writing the checkbox html code. Thanks mate.

Comment: by the way, is there a way to choose a comment as the correct answer?

Comment: Creating your html manually like that in the extension method is terrible practice and you ignoring all the features that extension methods provide - incorrect 2-way model binding, not checking `ModelState`, not rendering the `data-val` attributes etc etc. Strongly recommend you study the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Fix**

As we discussed in the OPs comments you need to set the value of the checkbox in your HTML helper. Write the `checked=checked` part when writing the check box HTML code

> Your hard coding `value="true"` on the input tags, shouldn't this be set
>   based on the model property?

**Alternative Solution**

Creating your HTML manually like this in extension methods isn't best practice and you will be ignoring all the features that extension methods provide

1. incorrect 2-way model binding
2. ModelState validation
3. not rendering the `data-val` attributes

So, if all you need to do is insert some HTML after an HTML tag you can use a scripting language to do this on the client side. The below example is written in jQuery.

*jQuery Example*

```
 $("<i class=\"no-rounded\"></i>").insertAfter("input .check-box");
```

Comment: OP is already setting the values correctly for both the checkbox (`value="true"`) and the hidden input (value="false"`). And no, its not set based on the model property (its the `checked` attribute that needs to be set based on the value of the property)